# Becoming a nazir nowadays

Tags: korban, nozir

I heard that if someone becomes a Nazir nowadays he can not get out of that state, since he has to bring a Korban to end his Nezirut and that is no longer possible due to the Churban. Is this written somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rambam Nazir 2:20

> נזירות נוהגת בפני הבית, ושלא בפני הבית; לפיכך מי שנדר בנזיר בזמן הזה--הרי זה נזיר לעולם, שאין לנו בית כדי שיביא קרבנותיו במלאות ימי נזרו.‏
> ... one who vowed to be a Nazir nowadays -- he is a Nazir forever for we don't have a Temple where he could bring his offerings at the completion of his [vow as a Nazir].

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cohen_(rabbi)

Comment: It seems we don't pasken like the Raavad, then. מקל בתער משנים עשר חודש לשנים עשר חודש, ומביא קרבנותיו שלוש בהמות כשיגלח I was unclear on the language; could someone be a *Nazir Olam* and thus razor off the long hair once a year today? Or does he mean the annual quasi-haircut needs korbanos too?